# Displaying JSON objects in a list with state and props

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to fetch a json file with info about several objects, but I can't seem to get it right. I am quite new to react so it is possible I am mixing up things wit this, state and props, or something else.

I have successfully received the list of objects from the json in the console, but I can't manage to display them in my return statement.

Thankful for help!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class PlayerFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            'playerList': []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getPlayers();
    }

    getPlayers() {
        fetch('http://link.to/json/players/')
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(results => console.log(results))
            .then(results => this.setState({'playerList': results}));
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <ul>
                    {this.props.state.map(function(players, index) {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                                <h1>{this.props.age}</h1>
                                <p>{this.props.height}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                }

                )}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <PlayerFeed />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you attach the responses here. Maybe it's related to the nested structure of your JSON responses.

Answer (score 0):

Props and state are fundamentally two different entities.

1. Props is data provided to your component
2. State is data defined in your component

Looking at your code, since it's a single level component, there are no props provided to it. You should change your code to -

```
{this.state.playerList.map(function(players, index) {
                return (
                    <div key={index}>
                            <h1>{players.age}</h1>
                            <p>{players.height}</p>
                    </div>
                )})}
```

Assuming your `playerList` object has `age` and `height` attributes.

Hope this solves :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should loop the playerList in state instead props.
props is got from parent component.

```
render() {
    return (
            <ul>
                {
                for(var player of  this.state.playerList) {
                  return (
                    <div key={player.index}>
                            <h1>{player.age}</h1>
                            <p>{player.height}</p>
                    </div>)
                }
            }
        </ul>
    );
}
```

Moreover you can install the react develop plugin in chrome to view the value in state and props.

Comment: there is no props to the component